# Reading from telnet misses some characters

Tags: c#

I need to read a bunch of line from device through telnet. When I start reading it the device send the data and finishes sending. The problem is when I review the received data I can see some characters are missing. What's the problem ?

Here's my function which does the receiving task:

```
//calling the function
string out_string = Encoding.Default.GetString(ReadFully(readStream,0));
//the function which read the data    
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream stream, int initialLength)
    {   if (initialLength < 1)
        {
            initialLength = 32768;
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[initialLength];
        int read = 0;

        int chunk;
        while ((chunk = stream.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length - read)) > 0 && (Byte)stream.ReadByte() != 65)
        {
            read += chunk;

            // If we've reached the end of our buffer, check to see if there's
            // any more information
            if (read == buffer.Length)
            {
                int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();

                // End of stream? If so, we're done
                if (nextByte == -1)
                {
                    return buffer;
                }

                // Nope. Resize the buffer, put in the byte we've just
                // read, and continue
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
                Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, buffer.Length);
                newBuffer[read] = (byte)nextByte;
                buffer = newBuffer;
                read++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: where did 'too localized' close option go?  I mean, is the s.o. now a board to help you with debugging your software?

Answer (score 0):

It's that second part of your while loop:

```
while ((chunk = stream.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length - read)) > 0 &&
   (Byte)stream.ReadByte() != 65)  //<-- Here
```

Your always reading an extra byte in each loop and (if it's not 65) never storing that byte anywhere.

Note, [`Stream.ReadByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readbyte.aspx):

> Reads a byte from the stream and **advances the position within the stream by one byte** ...

(**My emphasis**)

Comment: no that's not cause I absolutely need the second part to end the loop cause the device is sending data instantly and the end of my data is "ATAPLP=5010" so I need to keep track of the 'A' character.

Comment: @saadatrahimi - but what if the byte `ReadByte()` returns isn't `A`? Where does it go? Does it end up in `buffer`?

Comment: you see my the data starts "read" and ends with "ATAPLP=5010" and I get all output. the problem is within the output some characters such as '/' or some numbers (comparing to the expected data) are missing

Comment: @saadatrahimi - you have the "expected data" in front of you, we don't - so unless you'd care to add it to the question, I can't comment on it. What I can comment on, though, is that that call to `ReadByte` **is** going to read a byte from the stream, and that byte **isn't** being stored anywhere.

Comment: aha I get what you say so how can I fix it?
sample output :CS4c77777560 8:44:15 1392/4/10   
CS4c777774b0 8:44:50 1392/4/10   
CS4c222224b0 8:44:56 1392/4/10   
CS4c77777560 8:45:1 1392/4/10   
CS4c777774b0 9:55:18 1392/4/10   
CS4c2222560 9:55:26 1392/4/10   
CS4c222224b0 11:35:43 1392/4/10   
CS4c22222560 11:36:11 1392/4/10   
C4c222224b0 11:38:20 1392/4/10   
CS4c77777560 11:38:29 1392/4/10   
CS4c22222560 11:40:6 1392/4/10   
CS4c777774b0 12:5:32 1392/4/10   
CS4c222224b0 12:5:42 1392/4/10   
CS4c77777560 12:6:47 139/4/10   
CS4c22222560 12:7:2 1392/4/10

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do with this check, and why you thought it was appropriate to only do it once during each loop, despite not knowing how many bytes are read by each call to `Read` - perhaps, before doing `read += chunk`, you ought to scan `buffer` from `read` to `read+chunk` to see if it contains an `A`?

Comment: Thank you. but I figured out the problem.when I debug and put a break point before receiving the data from device and the device send all data(I mean delaying the receiving for about 5 seconds). then I continue I get all data correctly.
Here's my new question : how can I delay receiving data? is there a method or something?

Comment: @saadatrahimi - no, the right thing to do is what you're currently doing - loop until you detect that you've received all of the data - but the right way to do that is to look inside `buffer`, **not** to call `ReadByte`.

Comment: I changed the code with "do while " instead of while and put the condition there. I know delaying is not efficient but I can't figure out how to solve other than that. I tried but did not succeed.

Comment: @saadatrahimi - it's *not* the looping construct you use that's going to make the difference - it's stopping yourself from calling `ReadByte` that will. I don't know how else to explain this - I've tried something like 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional `(Byte)stream.ReadByte() != 65` is throwing away a character if it is not 65 (ASCII A).